# Open Image from Sentinel 1 in SNAP problems

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I have download SNAP today but I'm facing few problems with upload the image.
I have download image from Copernicus Open Acess Hub but whenever I download it I can't open it properly. 
those are the filles that were downloaded-
[image]

in measruemnet there are two images -vv and vh, as I download, but  as two different images.
When I open one of it in SNAP, I get one image with one band that looks like this-

[image]

whenever I try to run any process on the image I get this error message-
[image]

how can I solve this and upload image to the SNAP?

Comment: Please do not bother unzipping the downloaded zip file. SNAP `File > Open Product` can open the zip file as-is and then recognizes all associated information such as tie points.

Comment: sometimes unzipping can help to reduce the computing time to open a new image. If opening the zip file takes too long, it can be unzipped, but instead of opening the GeoTiff, the manifest.safe has to be selected under File > Open